# How to get a timestamp on rsync output

Tags: cron, rsync

I have an hourly crontab job

```
@hourly rsync -avc --delete /DirA/ /DirB/ >  /home/job.txt
```

However when I check the logbook I see no timestamps. How can I get timestamps in the log so that I can be able to see when error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@hourly (date; rsync -avc --delete /DirA/ /DirB/) &>  /home/job.txt
```

Note that I used `&> /home/job.txt` which redirects both the standard output and the standard error to the log file. That way you will also see any errors produced. Then, I use the `date` command to generate a timestamp before running the `rsync`. Placing the commands in parentheses makes the two run in the same subshell and allows the redirection of both commands' output at once.

Comment: Thank you! Will this append to the job.txt or will overwrite the txt everytime?

Comment: @ECII it will overwrite, I assumed that's what you wanted because that's what your original command did. If you want to append instead of overwriting, use `&>> /home/job.txt` instead.

Comment: @terdon When I use your command, I get a blank output. When I remove the date, parentheses and "&" it works.